# Is there a migration path Visual Studio C++ 2008 Application with a current Oracle ODBC driver depending onVisual Studio 2017 Redistributables?

Tags: c++, oracle, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, odbc

I am currently investigating the migration path of a Visual Studio C++ 2008 Application to be able to attached to an Oracle 19 Database via a current ODBC driver. Currently an 11.2 OCI interface running against an Oracle 11.2 database is used. The Application Codebase is too big to be migrated to Visual Studio 2017; It is planned to upgrade the database to Oracle 19.x

Is there any chance to use the current ODBC/OCI Drivers which needs Visual Studio 2017 Redistribution?
-> -    https://www.oracle.com/de/database/technologies/instant-client/microsoft-windows-32-downloads.html

Visual Studio C++ 2008 is not able to use a dll which needs more current Redistribution version directly, Is it possible to encapsulate the ODBC calls in another dll to be able to be used with Visual Studio C++ 2008?

Or do you see another migration path?

Thanks for input!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "current ODBC driver"?

Comment: Even if it would be some work, you should really consider to migrate to current version of Visual Studio. Sooner or later your application will stop working due to incompatible environment.

Comment: with current ODBC Driver I meant the one out of Oracle 19c client which depends on Visual Studio 2017 Runtime

Comment: I agree at the end there is no workaround migrating to a more modern Visual C++

Comment: According [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions (Doc ID 207303.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1) you need client version 11.2 or newer in order to connect to Oracle 19c server. Perhaps ODBC driver version 11.2 still works with VS C++ 2008

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes that's true, I found out that the oracle odbc shipped wirh Oracle 11.2.0.4 complies to ODBC 3.5.1 and works together with Visual Studio 2008, Only I have to check if the ODBC SDK for Visual C++ already supports ODBC 3.5